# Trying to merge multiple UPDATE statements into one within SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update, left-join

I have multiple update statements in a stored procedure (as shown below).

Question is I am trying to combine them into one UPDATE statement as there is a performance issue (takes longer to execute stored procedure). I tried putting columns (such as PONUMBER, VENDORID etc) in a single update statement but it is throwing errors.

Please suggest.

```
     UPDATE rptMaster SET  PONUMBER = (select top 1 poMaster.PONUMBER from poMaster where poMaster.ITEMNMBR =rptMaster.ITEMNMBR and 
        poMaster.UnCommited > 0)

    UPDATE rptMaster SET  VENDORID = (select top 1 poMaster.VENDORID from poMaster where poMaster.ITEMNMBR =rptMaster.ITEMNMBR and 
    poMaster.UnCommited > 0)

    UPDATE rptMaster SET  DUEDATE = (select top 1 poMaster.REQDATE from poMaster where poMaster.ITEMNMBR =rptMaster.ITEMNMBR and 
    poMaster.UnCommited > 0)

    UPDATE rptMaster SET  POQTYORDER = (select top 1 (poMaster.QTYORDER / rptMaster.UOMQTY) from poMaster where poMaster.ITEMNMBR =rptMaster.ITEMNMBR and 
    poMaster.UnCommited > 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is similar to polkduran's:

```
 WITH PO AS (
     SELECT  PONUMBER
        ,    VENDORID
        ,    REQDATE
        ,    QTYORDER
        ,    ITEMNMBR
        ,    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMNMBR ORDER BY ??) as RN
     FROM    poMaster
     WHERE   UnCommited > 0
    )
 UPDATE rptMaster 
 SET  PONUMBER = po.PONUMBER
 ,    VENDORID = po.VENDORID 
 ,    DUEDATE = po.REQDATE
 ,    POQTYORDER = po.QTYORDER / rptMaster.UOMQTY
 FROM rptMaster
     JOIN PO
          ON  PO.ITEMNMBR = rptMaster.ITEMNMBR 
          and PO.RN = 1
```

I'm using a Common Table Expression (CTE) to assign a row number to each `poMaster` record, with the records for each value of `ITEMNMBR` numbered separately.  This allows us to pick to the first record for each `ITEMNBR` in our `JOIN`, later, similar to the way you were using Top 1 in your subqueries.

Please note, though:  because you didn't indicate how you wanted to select the Top 1 record in your query, I had to leave the ORDER BY clause in the CTE unspecified.  (I put `??` in as a placeholder.)  You need to specify one or more sort fields in place of the `??` so it knows how to sort and number the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an update using a join clause:

```
update rpt
set
    PONUMBER = po.PONUMBER,
    VENDORID = po.VENDORID,
    DUEDATE = po.REQDATE,
    POQTYORDER = (po.QTYORDER / rpt.UOMQTY)
from rptMaster rpt
inner join poMaster po
    on po.ITEMNMBR = rpt.ITEMNMBR
where po.UnCommited > 0
```

I don't have a way to test it right now but that might work.

Comment: But what about the Top 1 requirement?  The OP might care which values of poMaster were used to update `rptMaster`.